argv changes are not reflected in /proc/pid/cmdline
I tried to verify content of cmdline after changing argv values, updated values are not reflected:
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s arg1 arg2 .. \n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("PID:%d\n", getpid());
    //Print the original arguments
    for (int i=0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d]:%s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }

    getchar();
    printf("Modifying arguments\n");
    argv[0] = "Hello";
    argv[1] = "123" ;
    for (int i=0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d]:%s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    


    return 0;
}

Output is same as before updating arguments. Is this correct behavior

procfs(5) reads: the process modifies its argv strings, those changes will show up here (/proc/pid/cmdline). This is not the same thing as modifying the argv array. Pay attention to this is not the same thing as modifying the argv array

You need to use strcpy() to overwrite the strings in place.
